# Getting Â and â characters in Linux PuTTY console

Tags: linux, special-characters

I am very much annoyed by **â** and **Â** being outputted in the manual outputs of most commands I run.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

I am using PuTTY in SSH mode and my Linux server is customized by Amazon EC2.

```
echo $TERM
xterm

Â´BÂ´ :Bold_Disable/Enable_toggle
              This command will influence use of the âboldâ terminfo capability and alters both the summary area and task area for the  Â´cur-
              rentâ window.  While it is intended primarily for use with dumb terminals, it can be applied anytime.

              Note:  When  this  toggle  is On and top is operating in monochrome mode, the entire display will appear as normal text.  Thus,
              unless the âxâ and/or âyâ ...
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Is your terminal configured to display UTF-8? Try to keep locale and terminal setting in accord. If connecting through ssh, you should take the target machine's locale into consideration, too.

In PuTTY, go to Settings -> Window -> Translation -> UTF-8

Comment: How can i check that in putty? my terminal type is echo $TERM
xterm

Comment: The encoding is not related to terminal type or $TERM. In PuTTY, go to *Settings -> Window -> Translation*.

Answer (score 2):

The default putty window translation is Latin-1, but needs to be UTF-8.

[image: Screen shot of where in the putty interface the change needs to be made]